# dart - Avoiding Recursion Stackoverflow by Asynchronously Waiting

Tags: dart

I'm having trouble understanding how a Fibonacci code made in DART works.

```
void main() async {
  List<BigInt> lista = [];
  final start = DateTime.now();
  finobacciPOC(lista, BigInt.from(15000), BigInt.zero, BigInt.one);
  print('lista');
  final time_exec = start.difference(DateTime.now());
  print("Calculate in time ${time_exec}");
}

void finobacciPOC(
    List<BigInt> listResult, BigInt total, BigInt start, BigInt end) async {
  BigInt sum = start + end;

  await Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 1));

  listResult.add(sum);
  total = total - BigInt.one;

  if (total == BigInt.zero) {
    print(listResult);
    return;
  }

  finobacciPOC(listResult, total, end, sum);
}
```

The code only works if you keep the delayed routine (in case you want to generate 15000 sequences). If you remove the delay, an overflow error will be displayed.

I want to understand how this scenario works.

Comment: Please post your code as text so we can try it without needing to rewrite it manually from your screenshot.

Comment: OK, the code has been posted below to help with understanding/testing

Comment: The reason it is failing is because you are trying to make `15000` nested calls which ends up going over the default stack limit of Dart. I suggest to rewrite the code so it is not making use of recursive method calls if you need to make this kind of calculations.

Comment: @julemand101 you covered the obvious part - why it fails without await. But why it does not fail with await?

Comment: @Lesiak Because `async` methods works different. What happens here is not really nested calls anymore but instead events on an event queue. So it does not make use of the call stack in the same way and you are therefore not hitting the stack limit.

Comment: General idea is: async transforms the code so that stack frames are stored on the heap, not on the stack. It is described in [async.md](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/7477a6cdf32b25a5b6cf058f1d305f5a306406b6/runtime/docs/async.md). But I hope someone can explain it in clear and precise way (I know details of .net async implementation, but not the one in dart)

Comment: Instead of `Future.delayed` you can also just do: `await Future<void>.value();` to get the same behavior. (or actually also just: `await null;`) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it "works" is because your method is `async` but you are not awaiting the implicit returned `Future`. That means that your current code does not really add anything to the callstack since each `finobacciPOC` will be running "independent" since the recursive call you are doing are never awaiting the returned `Future`.

Another way to see your code is the following where I have removed the `await` and converted it into what your code is really doing:

```dart
void finobacciPOC(
    List<BigInt> listResult, BigInt total, BigInt start, BigInt end) {
  BigInt sum = start + end;

  Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 1)).then((_) {
    listResult.add(sum);
    total = total - BigInt.one;

    if (total == BigInt.zero) {
      print(listResult);
      return;
    }

    finobacciPOC(listResult, total, end, sum);
  });
}
```

Here it becomes more clear that we are actually not have recursive calls on our call stack since the call to `finobacciPOC` will finish immediately after creating a new `Future` from `Future.delayed` which will end up making a new event on the event queue after the provided `Duration` of time have elapsed.

If you e.g. change your method so it now specify the returned Future and makes it so it `await` the recursive call:

```dart
Future<void> finobacciPOC(
    List<BigInt> listResult, BigInt total, BigInt start, BigInt end) async {
  BigInt sum = start + end;

  await Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 1));

  listResult.add(sum);
  total = total - BigInt.one;

  if (total == BigInt.zero) {
    print(listResult);
    return;
  }

  await finobacciPOC(listResult, total, end, sum);
}
```

It will start crashing with stackoverflow errors because this change would actually mean we do have a call stack in play again.

This change would be needed if we want a given caller of `finobacciPOC` to know for sure when the method is done running and the `listResult` actually contains the result.

E.g. in your code, you don't actually know in your `main` when the `finobacciPOC` is done which also means your counting of spend time is wrong.

Comment: Clear and precise :)

Comment: @Lesiak Well, and then we do have this example which works but I am not completely sure why and why the difference from using the `await`: https://gist.github.com/julemand101/df1f703bc0f1e72102a1d72bef21988f . But it might be some clever combination of futures when using `then`.